# fork multiple processes to listen()/accept()

Tags: c, unix, process, fork

```
struct sockaddr_in srv;
fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
setsockopt(fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEPORT, ...);

srv.sin_family = AF_INET;
srv.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
srv.sin_port = htons(9900);
bind(fd, (const struct sockaddr *)&srv, sizeof srv);

for (i = 0; i < MAX_PROCS; i++) {
   pid = fork();
   if (pid == 0) {
       /* child context */
       listen(fd, MAXCONN);
       connfd = accept(fd, NULL, NULL);
       ...
       close(connfd);
   } else 
}
```

I removed error checks and other pieces for brevity. This code works, I can `telnet` on localhost:9900 and see the connection. However

```
% lsof -i :9900
```

reports that all LISTEN connections belong to the socket with the same inode, which think it makes sense, since the socket is created once in the parent, and every child shares it.

So I think if I want really multiple listeners on the same `address:port` tuple, I should be doing bind() - listen() sequence per child. Is that correct?

However this results in error: `bind()` returns EINVAL and I get only one child created:

```
for (i = 0; i < MAX_PROCS; i++) {
    pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0) {
       srv.sin_family = AF_INET;
       srv.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
       srv.sin_port = htons(9900);
       bind(fd, (const struct sockaddr *)&srv, sizeof srv);
       ...
       listen();
       accept();
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Check the return value and errno. The second (and subsequent) probably fails with EADDRINUSE

Comment: @wildplasser. Thanks for reply. So the SO_REUSEPORT option not sufficient?

Comment: @wildplasser. May be I was not clear -- bind() returns EINVAL for all in the loop except for the first one.

Comment: Just check the return value. It is there for a reason.

Comment: @wildplasser, as I wrote earlier, the return value is EINVAL.

Comment: {address, portnumber} is a unique resource that can only be used once. Once you bind to it, you (or another process) cannot bind to it again. And: you should initialize your sockadress structure. (and you should not use SO_REUSEPORT before understanding the basics, IMHO)

Answer (score 1):

The portable Unix way is to call `socket`, `bind`, `listen` in the main process/thread. `accept` is then callbed by child processes/threads.

You may like to set `SO_REUSEADDR` option before `bind` to allow for quick restarts of your server.

---

On Linux, each child can create its own socket, set `SO_REUSEPORT`, and then call `bind`, `listen`, `accept`. See [`man socket(7)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/socket.7.html):

> `SO_REUSEPORT`
>
> Permits multiple `AF_INET` or `AF_INET6` sockets to be bound to an
> identical socket address.  This option must be set on each
> socket (including the first socket) prior to calling `bind`
> on the socket.  To prevent port hijacking, all of the processes binding to the same address must have the same effective UID.  This option can be employed with both TCP and UDP
> sockets.
>
> For TCP sockets, this option allows `accept` load distribution in a multi-threaded server to be improved by using a distinct listener socket for each thread.  This provides improved
> load distribution as compared to traditional techniques such
> using a single `accept`ing thread that distributes connections, or having multiple threads that compete to `accept`
> from the same socket.
>
> For UDP sockets, the use of this option can provide better
> distribution of incoming datagrams to multiple processes (or
> threads) as compared to the traditional technique of having
> multiple processes compete to receive datagrams on the same
> socket.

Comment: thanks for feedback. Setting `SO_REUSEPORT` and `SO_REUSEADDR` in the loop for every child created, does not help, i.e. `bind()` still fails with EINVAL. Creating per-child socket, setting SO_REUSEPORT and then bind-listen-accept effectively is the same as running the program multiple times, and that does work.

Comment: @Mark Your first sentence doesn't sound like you are doing the right thing. In main process you do `socket`, `SO_REUSEADDR`, `bind`, `listen`. In child you only do `accept`.

Comment: Having a single listener in the parent is a bottleneck. What I'm trying to do (I'm still learning socket programming), is create multiple listeners (on the same `address:port`), each one in its own child process. I know that this does not scale, and pthreads are preferred, but for now I only want to get this simple thing working.